# multifunction printer advice needed

Tags: printing

I am using Ubuntu LTS 22.04.2 desktop edition on my homeoffice environment. First of all I am not all good at  printer devices and I do not have any experience with printers on Linux

I need a multifunction printer like printer/scanner/photocopy (fax option is not important). What I wanted to do with printer mostly monochrome print, pdf/bill/ebook print

I am also looking for auto-dublex print, wifi support and low price for per print

I think I must look for laser or inktank printers but I need brand and model advices

Thank you for any advice

Comment: Start your research at https://openprinting.github.io/